# Override monaco editor hover widget style to hide "peek problem"

Tags: monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco

I was looking for a configurable way to hide the "Peek Problem" link but couldn't find.

Now I'm trying to override the hover tooltip widget css but so far no good..

I couldn't even trace it in devtools, where was it rendered??

[image]

I initially thought that the right place to look at was [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/84cb11350af589168660b037443aae0d8f9f36f6/src/vs/base/browser/ui/hover/hover.css)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Found it...](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/eff2fb75151dac67b6835584b6e91808ec1379ae/src/vs/editor/contrib/hover/modesContentHover.ts#L568)

```
  div.hover-row.status-bar {
    display: none !important;
  }
```